# How to create a bar chart that counts how many times comma separated values appears?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

My data(a column) is from a question which allowed multiple responses. So in each cell I have something like "A,C,E" and I'd like to create a bar chart with each answer as a category(A,B,C,D and E). I know the basics of pivot tables. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `=CountIf(A1:A3,"*A*")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTITUTE` and `LEN` to count the number of commas.

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))
```

For example that would return:

```
A,C,E       2
A,C,E,F     3
A,C,E,D,E   4
```

If you actually want to analyse each letter (which I think is what you really want to do), then you'll need something more like the equivalent of `explode` in PHP. There's some more information at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-columns-with-functions-49ec57f9-3d5a-44b2-82da-50dded6e4a68

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using the formula =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("A",cellname)),1,0).
Problem solved.